# R Shiny renderImage() does not recognize object 'input'

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

Why does `renderImage()` not recognize `input` in the code sample below:

```
library(d3heatmap)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


    ui <- fluidPage(
      h1("A heatmap demo"),
      selectInput("palette", "Palette", c("YlOrRd", "RdYlBu", "Greens", "Blues")),
      checkboxInput("cluster", "Apply clustering"),
      downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download Heatmap'),
      d3heatmapOutput("heatmap")
)

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({
        d3heatmap(
          scale(mtcars),
          colors = input$palette,
          dendrogram = if (input$cluster) "both" else "none"
) })

    output$downloadPlot <- renderImage(
        d3heatmap(scale(mtcars), colors = input$palette, dendrogram = if (input$cluster) "both" else "none"), 
        env = parent.frame(), 
        quoted = FALSE, 
        deleteFile = FALSE
        )

    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is my error:

`Error in match.arg(dendrogram) : object 'input' not found`

When I remove the `dendrogram = if (input$cluster) "both" else "none"` line, I get the following error concerning `input` again:

`Error in toPaletteFunc(pal) : object 'input' not found`

It seems a bit counterintuitive that the object `input` isn't found, as I've explicitly defined it upstairs with: `server <- function(input, output, session)`.

I've already examined existing Stack Overflow posts that generate a similar error message (e.g., [R Shiny error: object input not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483389/r-shiny-error-object-input-not-found)).

Code sample above was inspired by: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/d3heatmap/d3heatmap.pdf

Comment: `renderImage` used with the `imageOuput`. `downloadButton` with the `downloadHandler`. Read the docs.

Comment: Without `downloadButton` this code works. You should write a handler for the `downloadButton`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3heatmap()` produce the `htmlwidgets` class object. We can use `saveWidget()` function from the `htmlwidgets` package to save plot.

```
library(d3heatmap)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("A heatmap demo"),
    selectInput("palette", "Palette", c("YlOrRd", "RdYlBu", "Greens", "Blues")),
    checkboxInput("cluster", "Apply clustering"),
    downloadButton('download', 'Download Heatmap'),
    d3heatmapOutput("heatmap")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    plot <- reactive({
        d3heatmap(
            scale(mtcars),
            colors = input$palette,
            dendrogram = if (input$cluster) "both" else "none"
        )
    })
    output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({
        plot()
    })
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste0("d3heatmap-", tolower(input$palette), ".html")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            saveWidget(plot(), file)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you need save a plot as png see this discussion: https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/95. In short: now `htmlwidgets` does not support export plots as png or svg. You can see [exportwidget](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/exportwidget) and [webshot](https://github.com/wch/webshot) packages as workground.

Comment: Accepted and also +1 from me for very nice, clean code.  Would it be possible for you to show if there is a way to export a plot as pdf/jpg/tiff/etc?  I understand that png/svg are off the table, but maybe there is a clever way to produce one of these alternatives.

Comment: I think exportwidget library would be much more promising than webshot for this specific question because the code of exportwidget looks cleaner IMHO, which would make a perfect companion to this R code.  However, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to adapt exportwidget's R code to this specific question, as they seem to be doing much more complex things (e.g., multiple htmlwidgets, digraphs, etc).