# Unable to set size with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I m struggling to set size of points based on a parameter value "clicks" in my case, Ideally size command should work but its not working for me somehow.Its throwing me error **Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: size**
Here is my effort :

```
 library(ggmap)
    library(ggplot2)
    map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -73.99, lat = 40.75), color = "bw", scale = 2,zoom=12)
   x <- ggmap(map,extent = "device") +geom_point(aes(longitude.x, latitude.x,colour=factor(geo_region)), 
                                              data=data_ny, na.rm=T,size=3)+ scale_size_continuous(range =range(data_ny$clicks))
x
```

The DPUT is :

```
structure(list(geo_region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NY", class = "factor"), 
    io_id = c(262046L, 262045L, 262048L, 262046L, 262048L, 262048L, 
    262045L, 262046L, 262046L, 262048L, 262048L, 262046L, 262046L, 
    262048L, 262048L, 262046L, 262046L, 262048L, 262046L, 262048L, 
    262045L, 262046L, 262048L, 262045L, 262048L, 262045L, 262046L, 
    262048L, 262045L, 262046L, 262045L, 262048L, 262046L, 262048L, 
    262045L, 262046L, 262048L, 262045L, 262046L, 262046L, 262045L, 
    262048L, 262046L, 262045L, 262048L, 262045L, 262048L, 262046L, 
    262046L, 262048L), city.x = c("new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", "new york", 
    "new york", "new york"), latitude.x = c(40.75, 40.75, 40.75, 
    40.72, 40.72, 40.73, 40.73, 40.73, 40.7, 40.7, 40.71, 40.71, 
    40.71, 40.71, 40.71, 40.71, 40.71, 40.71, 40.72, 40.72, 40.72, 
    40.74, 40.74, 40.74, 40.74, 40.74, 40.74, 40.72, 40.72, 40.72, 
    40.72, 40.72, 40.72, 40.73, 40.73, 40.73, 40.75, 40.75, 40.75, 
    40.75, 40.75, 40.75, 40.76, 40.76, 40.76, 40.76, 40.76, 40.76, 
    40.76, 40.76), longitude.x = c(-73.99, -73.99, -73.99, -73.99, 
    -73.99, -73.99, -73.99, -73.99, -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, 
    -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, -73.98, -73.98, 
    -73.98, -73.99, -73.99, -73.99, -74, -74, -74, -74, -74, 
    -74, -74, -74, -74, -74.01, -74.01, -74.01, -73.98, -73.98, 
    -73.98, -73.97, -73.97, -73.97, -73.99, -73.99, -73.99, -73.99, 
    -73.99, -73.99, -73.98, -73.98), clicks = c(30L, 0L, 9L, 
    12L, 3L, 15L, 0L, 30L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 22L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 15L, 14L, 0L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 44L, 9L, 0L, 11L, 
    0L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 0L, 11L, 20L, 0L, 49L, 24L, 0L, 12L, 13L, 
    0L, 15L, 0L, 14L, 30L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("geo_region", 
"io_id", "city.x", "latitude.x", "longitude.x", "clicks"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the sample output i get if i fix Size = 4 [image]

But i want size to be dynamic based on clicks. Ideally **size=data_ny$clicks** should work, but its not, can anybody help me fix this trivial issue.

Comment: I assume data_ny$clicks is with shiny? to make it work you would need to use aes_string()

Comment: I am still not sure about how to replace this, so basically you are telling substituting aes() by aes_string() would work ?

Comment: here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483389/r-shiny-error-object-input-not-found/28483695#28483695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had an errors in the names and I thought that adding an alpha (transparency) specification would help resolve issues of nearly adjacent overlapping points with different numbers of clicks:

```
 x <- ggmap(map,extent = "device") + 
     geom_point(data=data_ny, aes(x=longitude.x, y=latitude.x), 
                color="blue", alpha=0.3,    
                size=na.omit(data_ny$clicks), na.rm=TRUE ) + 
      scale_size_continuous(range =range(data_ny$clicks))
 png(); print(x); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it works, just another question, can we change colors as well based on let say "city.x" column ? this data set has just one value but the entire data set would have more values.

Comment: I don't see why not. I tested by assigning `color` to this new variable: `data_ny$Up.v.Down <- as.numeric(factor( data_ny$latitude.x > mean(data_ny$latitude.x)))`